# Como soluciono un error que me da Visual Studio, , sitio web vacío asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

Buen día!
Quisiera que me pudieran ayudar a solucionar un problema con visual studio.
Actualmente estoy haciendo una guía de ejercicios y estoy trabajando con asp.net con sitio web vacío, pero al momento que lo quiero correr me muestra el mensaje y me dice:
No se puede conectar con el servidor web de desarrollo configurado.
Lo  curioso es que antes no me daba ningún[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] error

Comment: revisaste las propiedades del proyecto ? concretamente la solapa web para ver que configuracion de IIS esta configurada

Comment: valida en el try icon el que esta al costado del horario en la toolbar de windows si tienes el IIS Expresss iniciado, si esta detenlo. Tambien prueba cerrando el VS y volviendolo abrir, a veces una mala detencion ocasiona que el servicio quede lockeado

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema y lo solucioné con los siguientes pasos:

1. Cierre todas sus ventanas de Visual Studio, incluido el proyecto del error.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Vaya al proyecto de ruta sln y ábralo con una herramienta de edición de texto.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Busque la variable localhost y cambie el puerto a puerto: 80
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. Guarde el archivo y abra la solución con Visual Studio IDE, compile y ejecute el proyecto.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]